# How to Produce a Valid Token

Tags: tokens

I'm trying to create a custom token. I've already successfully implemented `hook_token_info`, and the token shows up. However, whenever I insert a the token `[site:chosen-school-year]` wherever I'm able, it doesn't show up.

Here's the code to implement the token:

```
function capstone_tokens_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()){
    $replacements = array();
    $sanitize = !empty($options['sanitize']);

    if ($type = 'site'){
        foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
            switch($name){
            case 'chosen-school-year':
                $replacements[$original] = getSelectedSchoolYear();
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    return $replacements;
}
```

`getSelectedSchoolYear()` is a function that I use in a different location that works as it's meant to.

I've compared my code to the samples provided [here](https://www.oliverdavies.uk/blog/creating-and-using-custom-tokens-drupal-7/) and [here](https://benmarshall.me/drupal-custom-tokens/), and haven't found any clear discrepancies between my code and theirs. I have tried clearing the Drupal cache, but that didn't provide any results. Is there something else in the system that I should be checking/trying?

Comment: what is [$type = 'site'] ? Content type? I don't think you can use content type at that level - it should be $type = 'node' - which is the type of the  entity you are trying to extract data from

Comment: The `$type` is used, from my understanding, to help identify the tokens, for organization. `getSelectedSchoolYear()` runs a database query - would it help if I edited the question to include that code?